# count no. of vowels, consonants, and print their count and product in a string

Tags: java, string

In the Question we are given 2 strings and we have to count no. of vowels, no. of consonants and display their product individually for each string.

Expected Output
2 6 12
0 7 0

Output getting
0 0 0
2 6 12

Here is the code-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String s=sc.nextLine();
            alpha(s);
            System.out.println();
        }     
   }

   private static void alpha(String s)
   {
       int count=0;
       int length=s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)=='a' || s.charAt(i)=='e' || s.charAt(i)=='i' || s.charAt(i)=='o' || s.charAt(i)=='u')
            count++;
        }
        int c=length-count;
        int product = c * count;
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d",count,c,product);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to check why it's not working? Have you tried to debug it? Are you stuck on some specific problem? We will not do your homework for you. We can help you to understand how to do your homework.

Comment: nextInt() does not include a newline after the number. If you hit enter after the first number, the first String will be empty.

Comment: @RalfRenz I am  not able to understand what are you saying. Could you tell error in my code.

Comment: OK. Try this as input: "2 Hello" than hit enter than input "Hello World" than hit enter. Your programm will deliver output for "Hello" and "Hello World". Next try: input "2" than hit enter than input "Hello" than hit enter. Your programm will deliver output for empty String (the text between "2" and newline) and "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CandidateCode {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your number : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
            String s = sc.next();
            alpha(s);
        }
    }

    private static void alpha(String str) {
        int vCount = 0, cCount = 0;
        str = str.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                vCount++;
            } else if (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
                cCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of vowels: " + vCount);
        System.out.println("Number of consonants: " + cCount);
        System.out.println("Product of vowels and consonants :" + vCount * cCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this will only work for the limited character set 7 bit US_ASCII. It breaks even for 8 bit ISO-LATIN-1. But I guess the intention of the question was US_ASCII so it does answer the question as is.

Comment: It is giving the same output as mine, could you explain why have u converted string to lower case , and could u help to point the error in my code.

Comment: @ShivangiSingh now I edit the answer, I converted string to lower case, because alpha method can only check lower case letters